# Iron python - moving and updating files (using 2.7.3 version) when os and shutil don't exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, ironpython

I'm using Iron python and want to update my Dlls every time  I run my program.
I'm using 2 folders : "dest" and "src" containing the same files(Dlls).
I want my script to see if the "dest" folder contains the latest and the most updated dlls (in comparison to "src" folder) and if so - change them, else do nothing.

I looked here and searched google for this info and used this :

```
import shutil
src = "C:\\steve_test\\Test_xp\\added"
dst = "C:\\steve_test\\Test_xp\\moved"
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

also looked at the documentation here : https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/shutil.html

Another thing that was suggested is to use :

```
os.stat
```

but in both cases I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
>>> import shutil

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named shutil
```

anyone knows what to do? I really have no clue how to implement my code
any help would be very appriciated
thanks!

Comment: Are you running `ipy.exe` or embedded in another program? `os` and `shutil` should both be available to `ipy.exe`.

Comment: no, not running it. but its nor recognized

Comment: HOw did you install it? From the MSI or the zip file?